# How to bind ListView inside a RadRibbonDropDownButton in a grid cell template?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, radgridview

I have a rad grid view that binds its itemssource to a list of 'Employee's.
'Employee' entity has a list of 'Roles' property. How do I bind this 'Roles' to a `ListView` as below.

As an example: In second column, `RadComboBox` binds properly. In thrid column, `RadRibbonDropDownButton` doesn't bind properly.
How do i get RolesList bound to `ListView` inside `RadRibbonDropDownButton`?

Please help.

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Role> RolesList {get; set;}
}
class Role
{
    public int RoleId {get; set;}
    public string RoleName {get; set;}
    public string RoleCategory {get; set;}
}
<tk:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EmployeeList,Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <tk:RadGridView.Columns>
        <tk:GridViewDataColumn Header="Employee Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <tk:GridViewDataColumn Header="Roles" Width="410">
            <tk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--this binds properly-->
                    <tk:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RolesList}" DisplayMemberPath="RoleName" SelectedValuePath="RoleId" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </tk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        </tk:GridViewDataColumn>
        <tk:GridViewDataColumn Header="Roles" Width="410">
            <tk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <tk:RadRibbonDropDownButton>
                        <tk:RadRibbonDropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RolesList}">
                                <ListView.View>
                                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RoleName}" Header="Role Name" Width="75" ></GridViewColumn>
                                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RoleCategory}" Header="Role Category" Width="175" ></GridViewColumn>
                                    </GridView>
                                </ListView.View>
                            </ListView>
                        </tk:RadRibbonDropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                    </tk:RadRibbonDropDownButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </tk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        </tk:GridViewDataColumn>
    </tk:RadGridView.Columns>
</tk:RadGridView>
```

Comment: Uhm, why are you using a Ribbon-Element in a Gridview?

Comment: I want the drop down to be a grid

Answer (score 0):

Adding DataContext={Binding} fixed the binding problem.